# prestashop 1.7.4.4 search is not working in any other language

Tags: search, prestashop-1.7

i am using **Prestahop 1.7.4.4** on my localhost (WAMP) . 
my language is Persian . 
when i try to search in Persian , it shows 404 page . all of my products are in Persian language . 
i have already tried both of indexing options in Prestashop setting .

Comment: This question is hard to answer, as there are a lot of important details missing. Try to put yourself in the shoes of those who know nothing about your problem. Make sure to [edit] your question to include all **relevant** content. Providing a [mcve] will increase your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution about 1 year ago . i will explain it now if it may helps anyone . 
my problem was with MySql collation . it was on "latin1_swedish_ci" so i changed it to "utf_persian_ci" so my problem solved .

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related to indexing: Go into your back office, select Preferences->Search and Re-build entire index

Comment: I had the same problem. Thanks, i would never find this by myself, it is so ridiculous.